# What is the CORE logic/how they code the "required" built in validation rule of laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I just wanna know how they code the "required" validation rule of laravel.

I tried to add an required rule to an input that doesnt exist and the "required" rule run but if i changed to other rule like "email" or etc it doesnt runs. Im just curious.

what i mean to the input that doesnt exist is its really exist but it disyplay:none.

I Just wanna see the function logic.

Heres my sample code

```
$validator->sometimes("mmad_bonus_type", 'required', function($input){
        return $input->mmad_bonus_type == null;
});
```

Comment: This can easily be looked up in the docs. http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation

Comment: Yah i know how to add validation rule, but what im asking is how they code the built in "required" rule, i mean the pure code like the class or the function.

Comment: required just means it will error out if the given variable doesn't exist or holds no value.

Comment: pls remove ur downvote. i think my question confuses or you didnt get it

Comment: Yes sir, i know how the required works offcourse. now lets go back to my question which, "Where/How can i see the exact logic code for the required rule".

Comment: First off you asked what not where. If you wanna find the code, look at your call. It will tell you what class to look at. If you are looking to override the function then don't edit system files. Instead, create your own validation function and you dont need to look at the existing one to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is in the [`validateRequired` function](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8865d2276be94f0a3497ba3bd26c906ae9e91e1c/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php#L536) of `Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php` (which will be in your `vendor/laravel/framework/src` directory).

```
protected function validateRequired($attribute, $value)
{
    if (is_null($value))
    {
        return false;
    }
    elseif (is_string($value) && trim($value) === '')
    {
        return false;
    }
    elseif ((is_array($value) || $value instanceof Countable) && count($value) < 1)
    {
        return false;
    }
    elseif ($value instanceof File)
    {
        return (string) $value->getPath() != '';
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: thnx for your answer, what i did to find the file is create an error in my custom core validator class just to figure out where the main location of the file is.. thnx anyways